# List Button Names in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains buttons generated by JavaScript. The reason for this is that a user selects an item from the left column, a button containing the name of the item is added to the right (kind of like a shopping cart). If you click the button on the right the button is removed.

Div filled with some buttons looks like this:

```html
<div id="controllist2" style="position: fixed; padding-left: 10px;">
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
  <button id="swsc11" type="button" onclick="removeControlButton(this.id);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background: url(../../Images/controls/swsc.png) no-repeat; background-size: 28px;">swsc 1</button>
</div>
```

Is there a way to iterate through this div, get all the button html text and append them to a label?

I've looked around for a few hours and I can not find a good starting place.

Comment: You know that buttons don't require labels, right? If you do need them anyway, please show your intended markup result. Also, it seems like the function that creates the buttons should add the labels as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name of button ? Did you meant html from button ?

```
var label_text = '';
$('#controllist button').each(function(){
  label_text += $(this).html();
});

$('#controlllist').append('<label>'+label_text+'</label>');
```

Comment: Yes html text, haved edited question to more specific.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through something with jQuery, you can use `.each()`

You could do:

```
var buttonArray = [];
$('#controllist2 > button').each(function(i){
    var name = $(this).text();
    buttonArray.push(name);
});
console.log(buttonArray);
```

This starts a new array, iterates through the `#controllist2` div and looks at each button.  Makes a value with the button text (you can use `.attr('id')` or `.attr('class')` or whatever), then pushes it into that empty array.

Then you can do whatever you want with the button names.